# Executing applications automatically with python

Tags: python

I came across some ways to implement a search to get a list of all the installed applications on your operating system, may question is there a way to execute some of them either randomly or the first 3 of the list ?

```
import wmi
PATTERN = r"\newcommand*{{\Title}}{{{}}}"
w = wmi.WMI()
for p in w.Win32_Product():
    print (PATTERN.format(p.Version))
    print (PATTERN.format(p.Vendor))
    print (PATTERN.format(p.Caption))
    print("\hline")
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the path to the program, you can execute it using the `os` module in Python.  For example, if I have `python.exe` installed at `C:/program files/python36/python.exe`, I could run:

```
import os
os.system("C:/program files/python36/python.exe")
```

and it will open Python.